# CAST value with two decimals - 0.00.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I'd like to order values with two decimals/periods and wondering if there's CAST/Convert datatype that will allow me to do this.  Values are currently something like this:

```
1.11.1
1.11.10
1.11.11
1.11.2
1.11.21
1.11.3
```

I'd like them to be ordered like the following:

```
1.11.1
1.11.2
1.11.3
1.11.10
1.11.11
1.11.21
```

Comment: Are your values stored as strings / varchars ?

Comment: stored as varchars

Comment: Are you values all have same format? (with two decimals/periods)

Comment: Unfortunately no - there are some values like 1.11, 1.21 without the second decimal set.

Comment: This will require a fairly involved SQL, using `CHARINDEX` to get the position of the last period, then doing a `SUBSTRING` to extract the last numeric value after the period, putting this value and original value in a CTE and then ordering the CTE fields by the last numberic value `ASC` and selecting the original value :)

Comment: @Shiva we think alike....

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
('1.11.1'),
('1.11.10'),
('1.11.11'),
('1.11.2'),
('1.11.21'),
('1.11.3')

Select A.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Order By 
       cast(ParseName(SomeField,4) as int)
      ,cast(ParseName(SomeField,3) as int)
      ,cast(ParseName(SomeField,2) as int)
      ,cast(ParseName(SomeField,1) as int)
```

Returns

```
SomeField
1.11.1
1.11.2
1.11.3
1.11.10
1.11.11
1.11.21
```

Comment: @scsimon OK, that made me smile... First time today.  Thanks for that.

Comment: I literally dropped my head in defeat haha. +1 from my side. Cheers.

Comment: This is awesome. I learned something new today - `PARSENAME(...)`. Thanks @JohnCappelletti !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by splitting your values in a CTE and then ordering... Just replace #t with your table and c1 with your column name.

```
;with cte as(
select 
    c1, 
    LEFT(c1,CHARINDEX('.',c1) - 1) as LeftDigits,
    SUBSTRING(c1,CHARINDEX('.',c1) + 1,LEN(c1) - CHARINDEX('.',c1) - CHARINDEX('.',reverse(c1))) as MiddleDigits,
    RIGHT(c1,CHARINDEX('.',reverse(c1)) - 1) as RightDigits
from #t)


select * from cte
order by
LeftDigits,MiddleDigits,LEN(RightDigits),RightDigits
```

Here is some test data for everyone

```
select '1.11.1' as C1 into #t
union all select
'1.11.10'
union all select
'1.11.11'
union all select
'1.11.2'
union all select
'1.11.21'
union all select
'1.11.3'
union all select
'2.11.1'
union all select
'2.1.1'
union all select
'2.2.1'
union all select
'33.0.5'
union all select
'2.01.11'
```

And results....

[image: Results]

Comment: I see what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query but it is round about way

```
select numbers
from #testdecimal
order by convert(int,substring(substring(numbers,charindex('.', numbers)+1, len(numbers)), charindex('.', substring(numbers,charindex('.', numbers)+1, len(numbers)))+1, len(numbers)))
```

create table script:

```
create table #testdecimal
( numbers nvarchar(20)
)

insert into #testdecimal (numbers)
values
 ('1.11.1'  ),('1.11.10' ),('1.11.11' )
,('1.11.2'  ),('1.11.21' ),('1.11.3'  )
```